# Is it illegal to reference a known cartoon character in a drawing as an easter egg tribute?

Tags: united-states

Let's say I draw an image of a toy store with a lot of stuffed animals. On the shelf hidden away is a stuffed animal of Hobbes from Calvin and Hobbes as sort of an easter egg tribute. Would this be illegal?